# Opening some documents using java

Tags: java, solr

I have a index.jsp page. In this page, I'm filling the table dynamically with some records that I get Solr database. My script is like this;

```
<script>
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' )){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
function getData(){

    $('#example tbody').html('');
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO_copy:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName_copy:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType_copy:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            var html='';        
            $.each(docs,function(key,value){
                var arrayExtensions=["jpg","JPG","JPG File","jpeg","JPEG image","PNG","TIFF image","tiff"];
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center">'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><form method="POST" action="openDocumentServlet" target="_blank"><input name="document" value="'+value.FilePath+'" hidden><input name="docName" value="'+value.FileName+'" hidden><input id="buton" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm" value="OPEN"></form></td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center" onmouseover="mouseOver(this)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this)"><p><a href=""><img src="images//SoftwareIcons-21-512.png" width=50; height=50; name="'+value.FileName+'" id="'+value.FilePath+'" alt="'+arrayExtensions.indexOf(value.extType[0])+'"></a></p></td>';
                html+='</tr>';
            });

            $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#example tbody').html(html);
            var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting" : [],

            });
        },
    });


};
</script>
```

In this code snippet, I'm opening document (pdf,docx...)

```
html+='<td class="text-center"><form method="POST" action="openDocumentServlet" target="_blank"><input name="document" value="'+value.FilePath+'" hidden><input name="docName" value="'+value.FileName+'" hidden><input id="buton" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm" value="OPEN"></form></td>';
```

I'm using servlet to do this. My servlet codes like this.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Docpath=request.getParameter("document");
        String docname=request.getParameter("docName");
        File file=new File("T:/Temp/"+docname);
        Path filePath=Paths.get("T:/Temp/"+docname);
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(filePath));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+docname);
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            ServletOutputStream  outs =  response.getOutputStream ();

            File original=new File(Docpath);
            File destination=new File("T:/Temp/");
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(original, destination);
            InputStream input=new FileInputStream(file);
            bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
            bos=new BufferedOutputStream(outs);
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        }

        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

My document is in server side. I'm copying it local path like `T:/Temp/` and I'm opening the document in local path. It was running correctly sometimes ago but now it gives me this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.solr.openDocumentServlet.doPost(openDocumentServlet.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: does your server has a T drive? remember, it's not going to look for it on your local machine.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, it has. I found the reason of error. It gives me error because of `BufferedInputStream`. I'm still working on it.